# Erro ao tentar mudar larguras de colunas de TableView

Tags: java, javafx

Tenho um método que aumenta e diminui a largura da minha tabela ao clicar de um botão (ele funciona perfeitamente):

```
public void toggleTela()
{

    if(this.tblAudiencias.getWidth() == 940)
    {
        this.toogleItens(true);
        this.tblAudiencias.setMinWidth(649);
        this.tblAudiencias.setLayoutX(287);
        this.btnToggle.setText("< Ocultar");

    }
    else
    {
        this.toogleItens(false);
        this.tblAudiencias.setMinWidth(940);
        this.tblAudiencias.setLayoutX(5);
        this.btnToggle.setText("> Mostrar");
    }
    this.redefineColunas(this.tblAudiencias.getWidth());

}
```

O método `redefineColunas` deveria definir a largura das colunas de acordo com a da tabela:

```
private void redefineColunas(double tabela)
{
    this.colAudiencia.setMinWidth(tabela * 0.20);
    this.colData.setMinWidth(tabela * 0.15);
    this.colHora.setMinWidth(tabela * 0.10);
    this.colAutor.setMinWidth(tabela * 0.20);
    this.colReu.setMinWidth(tabela * 0.15);
    this.colProcesso.setMinWidth(tabela * 0.20);
}
```

O objetivo era dar umas porcentagens para cada coluna, quando entra no `else` ele funciona, aumenta a tabela e as colunas, mas quando clico no botão novamente para diminuir a tabela (entrar no `if`) a tabela é diminuida mas as colunas continuam grandes.

Answer (score 0):

Experimente incluir o método `setPrefWidth(tabela * valor)`, dentro do método `redefineColunas(double tabela)`, para definir a largura preferencial da coluna.